# I want to set session id

Tags: php, codeigniter, api

```
public function admin_login()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','E-mail','required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters("<p class='text-danger'>"," </p>");
    if( $this->form_validation->run())
    {
            $email=$this->input->post('email');
            $password=$this->input->post('password');
            $link='http://api.amid.tech/admin/'.$email.'/'.$password;
            $data = (array) json_decode(file_get_contents($link,true));
            if($email== $data['email'] && $password== $data['password'])
             {
            var_dump($data = (array)  json_decode(file_get_contents($link,true)));
            echo $userid=$this->session->set_userdata('name',$data);
            exit;
            $this->load->view('admin/dashboard');
             }
            else
             {
            // echo"false";
            $this->load->view('index');
            //echo validation_errors('');
             }
    }
}
```

I want to set session id in this code through api

Comment: What type of error/undesired behavior do you get?

Comment: it shows array but empty array no id set in session

Comment: Why this question is in css , html tag?

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter 2.X's session management is NOT implemented on top of PHP Sessions. So if you were trying to print `$_SESSION`, it will show up an empty array. Instead you should use `$this->session->userdata('key')`. `$_SESSION` should however work just fine if you are using CI 3.X.

Have a look at this:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html#step-6-update-your-session-library-usage

Comment: that is why you were not able to use $_SESSION, use `$this->session->userdata('key')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not Exactly sure what you want but if you have refereed  CI's user guide then, this can help you set session and save them in database.

**First Load The Session Library:**

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Now If you have some value in variable and want to store it into session then you can do this:

```
 $this->session->set_userdata('string', $variable);
```

If there is an array of data then as mentioned in user guide:

```
$newdata = array(
                   'username'  => 'johndoe',
                   'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
                   'logged_in' => TRUE
               );

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

And if you want a specific item from session then you can do:

```
echo $this->session->userdata('session-variable-name');
```

For all session data do:

```
var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());
```

And if you want to save your sessions to database then simply create a table called `ci_sessions`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
user_data text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
```

);

Like so.

> I suggest you to read the [user guide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) it has lot more.

Comment: function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library("session");
    } correct answer is that

Comment: you should have loaded that library in constructor or your base controller if you had any